# how to get DatakeyValue from gridview being populated with linq

Tags: c#, linq, gridview

I have the following gridview:

```
                <asp:GridView ID="gvNOVs" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" PageSize="10"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" BackColor="Transparent" GridLines="None"
            RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast" DataKeyNames="NOVID"
            OnRowDataBound="gvNOVs_RowDataBound"
            OnRowCommand="gvNOVs_OnSelectRow" 
            OnPageIndexChanging="gvNOVs_PageIndexChanging"
            OnSorting="gvNOVs_OnSorting"
            >
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alternateItemStyle" />
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerStyle" />
            <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" />
            <RowStyle CssClass="itemStyle" />

            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="NOVID" HeaderText="NOVID" InsertVisible="false" ReadOnly="true" Visible="false"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="NOVNumber" HeaderText="NOV Number" SortExpression="NOVNumber"
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="NOVDate" HeaderText="NOV Date" SortExpression="NOVDate"
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="Company Name" SortExpression="CompanyName"
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CargoTankID" HeaderText="Cargo Tank Number" SortExpression="CargoTankNumber"
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ARBInspectorFirstName" HeaderText="InspectorFirstName"
                    SortExpression="InspectorFirstName" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ARBInspectorLastName" HeaderText="InspectorLastName" SortExpression="InspectorLastName"
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ViolationName" HeaderText="Violation Name" SortExpression="ViolationName"
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

It is being populated on the page load event using linq:

```
                var NOVs = from n in db.CT_NOVs
                   join i in db.CT_Inspectors on n.ARBInspectorID equals i.CTInspectorID
                   join v in db.CT_ViolationTypes on n.ViolationTypeID equals v.ViolationTypeID
                   join t in db.CT_Tanks on n.CargoTankID equals t.CargoTankID
                   join c in db.CT_Companies on t.CompanyID equals c.CompanyID
                   orderby n.NOVNumber descending
                   select new
                   {
                       n.NOVID,
                       n.NOVNumber,
                       NOVDate = n.NOVDate.Value.ToShortDateString(),
                       ARBInspectorFirstName = i.FirstName,
                       ARBInspectorLastName = i.LastName,
                       v.ViolationName,
                       t.CargoTankID, 
                       c.CompanyName
                   };

        this.gvNOVs.DataSource = NOVs;
        this.gvNOVs.DataBind();
```

When I click on a row, I call this method:

```
protected void gvNOVs_OnSelectRow(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{


}
```

I'm not sure how to get the datakeyValue, I want to get the NOVID for the row that was clicked on.  If I get e.CommandArgument.ToString(), it gives me the value for CargoTankID, I have no idea why it gives me that value.

Anybody know how to get the NOVID for the row selected?

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

1. Get the index from the `CommandArgument`
2. Get the grid itself from the `CommandSource`
3. Get the data source
4. Get the data item at the index

   int index = int.Parse((string)e.CommandArgument);
   var grid = (GridView)e.CommandSource;
   var data = (IList)grid.DataSource;
   var NOVID = data[index].NOVID;

Answer (score 0):

you should try something like this

```
string dataKeyValue = (string)this.gvNOVs.SelectedDataKey.Value;
```

Comment: that didn't work, I've tried many variations, it says it's null